# nunit testing with azure devops pipelines

Tags: .net-core, azure-devops, automated-tests, nunit, integration-testing

I'm trying to follow this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/test/run-automated-tests-from-test-hub?view=azure-devops in order to run automated test, i'm using .net core 3.1 and tfs with nunit and vs 2019

the test is done with no errors but it didn't run my test cases[image]

and the config:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: could you share your task configuration?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk added to the question

Comment: and what is your test project name?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk the pipeline name is Testing Framework .Net-ASP.NET Core-CI (1) and the fully project name is Testing Framework .Net and the test dll is NUnitTestProject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error message "`##[warning]Project file(s) matching the specified pattern were not found.`" The pattern settings in `Test` step is incorrect.

If the test project name is `NUnitTestProject`, then please using the following pattern:

- Using the full name: `**/NUnitTestProject.csproj`
- Using wildcards : `**/*Test*.csproj`
- Alternately using the `**/*.csproj` (for all .csproj files in all subfolders), it will search all the projects
  absolutely including the test project.

[image]